# Rails 3 route scoping and/or nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, scope, nested, permalinks

I am having trouble scoping routes that I don't want to nest.

I have the following routes:

```
  resources :foos
  resources :bars
  resources :bazs do
    resources :hellos
    resources :worlds
  end
```

The foo, bar, and baz models all belong_to a user model. I don't want to nest another layer, but I do want to have a prefix in my url that corresponds to a user's permalink attribute (similar to each github repo prefixed by a username). So I have a before filter on all of my controllers

```
  def get_scope
    @user = User.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
  end
```

Modified to_param thanks to @cowboycoded

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
    def to_param
      permalink
    end
  end
```

I wrapped those routes with

```
  scope ":permalink", :as => :user do
    #nested routes here
  end
```

Now everything works fine as long as I pass @user to every non-index route. It doesn't seem very dry to have to go back to all of my views and replace (@foo) with (@user, @foo) when it is already scoped.

Unless I am mistaken, the to_param method simply replaces :id so that urls such as /users/:id appear as users/permalink instead of users/1. I attempted to use this :id in my scope, but it conflicts with foo's :id param and breaks everything. Maybe there is a connection to paths that I am missing?

Thanks for any suggestions that you may have!

Comment: Incorporated path helper solution and to_param method.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the to_param method in your model?  This will allow you to override the default and use something other than id, and will work with the URL helpers

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-to_param

Example from documentation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param  # overridden
    name
  end
end

user = User.find_by_name('Phusion')
user_path(user)  # => "/users/Phusion"
```

I'm not sure how well this plays with scope, since I haven't tried it, but I guess its worth a shot.